# Bootstrap NavWalker dropdown displaying in desktop but not mobile

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap navwalker to build out my navigation in Wordpress. I have got it all working except for the dropdown in mobile. For some reason the dropdown works perfectly fine in desktop view, but once in mobile nothing happens.

I have added the code from the header.php file below.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>">
      <img src="/wp-content/themes/Gaggia/assets/src/library/img/gaggia-logo.svg" class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll"
      aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height: 100px;">
        <?php
        wp_nav_menu( array(
          'theme_location'  => 'primary',
          'depth'           => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
          'container'       => 'div',
          'container_class' => 'nav',
          'container_id'    => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
          'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
          'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
          'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
      ) );
      
        ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening. I updated the actual walker file to match data-bs-toggle instead of just data-toggle. This fixed the issue for desktop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Added css class to resolve the issue.

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
    position: static;
}
```